# Find the minimum number multiple of 3 greater than a given natural number $n$

Tags: algorithms

**Problem:**

*Specify and solve the next problem:*

*Find the minimum number multiple of 3 greater than a given natural number $n$.*

**Solution:**

1. Specification:

$$\{Q: true\} S \{R: (k\ \text{mod}\ 3 = 0) \wedge k>n\}$$

2. Program (in GCL):

$[\text{Ctx:}\ C: n \in nat$

$\{Q: true\}$

$\ \ \ \ if\ n\ \text{mod}\ 3 = 0\rightarrow\ k:=n+3$

$\ \ \ \ []  n\ \text{mod}\ 3 = 1\rightarrow\ k:=n+2$

$\ \ \ \ []  n\ \text{mod}\ 3 = 2\rightarrow\ k:=n+1$

$\ \ \ \ fi$

$\{R: (k\ \text{mod}\ 3 = 0) \wedge k>n\}$

$]$

Is that correct?

I think I also need to specify in the post-condition that $k$ is the next multiple of 3.

Comment: For questions about program specification, you will do better on a programming or computer science forum.

Comment: Yeah.... If I'm reading you correctly that is it.  I'd phrase it as:  Let $n = 3k + r; 0 \le r < 3$ which by archimedean principal are unique.  Next multiple of three is $n + (3 - r) = 3k + 3 = 3(k+1)$.  Same idea though.

Comment: @RobArthan I've asked in this forum because someone suggested me that questions that involve logic (like the one in the specification of this problem) Math SE is better.

Comment: Good luck! You are unlikely to get much help on MSE with your example of Hoare logic for Guarded Command Language, which is (I think) the topic you are actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right idea.

I'd phrase it as: Let $n \equiv i \mod 3; i\in\{0,1,2\}$.  Then the desired number is $n + (3 - i)$.

[If $n = 3k +i$ then $n + (3-i) = 3(k+1)$.]

[So $3k \le n < 3(k+1)$.]

Comment: But your phrasing isn't GCL!

Comment: Ask a math question, you'll get a math answer.

Comment: Quite so! Hence my advice to the OP.